# Expo 35. Facebook Auth. Incorrect behaviour on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, expo

I've set up facebook authentication on Expo 35 as described here:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/v35.0.0/sdk/facebook/

I can authenticate in both expo and standalone ios apps.

The problem is that instead of opening the facebook app,

1. it shows a browser window as an overlay: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JnFp.png), [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6czH.png)
2. I'm not logged in to facebook in the browser. The browser prompts to open facebook app. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHsS8.png)
3. Facebook app prompts to authorize access, as expected. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbWAw.png)
4. But when I authorize access using the facebook app, I return back to the browser overlay, where I'm still not authenticated. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZNXo.png)

I can manually enter my facebook creds in the browser overlay and then I'll get authenticated correctly, but this is hardly called a user-friendly experience.

How do I make my app open Facebook app directly or, at least, how do I make the facebook app authorize the browser overlay?

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this? I have the same issue with expo 36

Answer (score 1):

According to this [1] post the Facebook app login feature is now deprecated due to Apple restriction policy. Only web one will stay.

On iOS FB SDK change log [2] many login related APIs are deprecated by version 5.0.0 of the SDK and version 5.5.0 has note:

> Replaced UIWebView with WKWebView as Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs

which implies the cause to be an Apple policy.

**Source:**

[1] https://forums.expo.io/t/sdk35-ios-facebook-login-doesnt-open-app/28567/3

[2] https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md